# A nonsplit short exact sequence of abelian groups with $B \cong A \oplus C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

A homework problem asked to find a short exact sequence of abelian groups
$$0 \rightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$ such that $B \cong A \oplus C$ although the sequence does not split. My solution to this is the sequence 
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{i}{\longrightarrow}
\mathbb{Z} \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}
(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow 0$$
with $i(x)=(2x,0,0,\dotsc)$ and $p(x,y_1,y_2,\dotsc)=(x+2\mathbb{Z},y_1,y_2,\dotsc)$.

My new questions:

1. Is there an example with finite/finitely generated abelian groups?
2. If the answer to (1) is negative, will it help to pass to general $R$-modules for some ring $R$?

Comment: FYI: A different example, still with infinite groups, is Example 6.35 of Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra (2nd ed., AMS).

Comment: In the 1st edition of Rotman's book it is on p. 437 (as part of the main text, not separated as a numbered example) and in the 3rd edition of Rotman's book ("Part 1") it is Example B-1.45 on pp. 307-308.

Answer (score 22):

There is no counterexample with $A,B,C$ finitely generated abelian groups.  There is, more generally, no counterexample with $A,B,C$ finitely generated modules over any noetherian ring $R$.

To see this, consider the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(C,A)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(B,A)\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(A,A).$$

The original sequence splits if and only if this sequence is exact on the right.  If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are of finite length as modules, this follows immediately just by counting lengths.  Otherwise, it's enough to show exactness after localizing and completing at an arbitrary prime $P$, and for this it's enough to show exactness after tensoring with $R/P^n$, and for this you can assume the lengths are finite, which is the case we've already dealt with.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite unfamiliar with techniques on localization and completion you're referring to. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @FrankScience:  Any standard textbook on commutative algebra will do.  My favorite is Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: I didn't read last chapters of Atiyah-Macdonald (that involves things like Artin-Rees). By *localization and completion*, I mean using this technique to reduce general cases to Artinian cases, which I cannot remember that appears in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: And on this specific problem, we know that exactness is stalk-local, and I believe that under some finiteness condition (like Noetherian, finitely presented, etc), split-ness is also stalk-local (since we have some base-change property of $\operatorname{Ext}$, maybe one can find some elementary proof, say passage from stalks to a fundamental open set). But for completion, I know nothing, except that it's an exact functor (under some finiteness condition).

Comment: @FrankScience :  Once you've reduced to $R$ local, with maximal ideal $P$, the completion $\hat{R}$ is faithfully flat over $R$, which means that a sequence of $R$-modules is exact if and only if it becomes exact after tensoring with $\hat{R}$..  But $\hat{R}$  is an inverse limit of the $R/P^k$, and exactness behaves well with respect to  inverse limits, so that exactness mod $P^k$ for each $k$ (which follows from counting lengths) implies exactness over the completion, as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explication. Did you use something like $\otimes\hat R$ commutes with $\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,\bullet)$? For the last comment, I want to add that inverse limits of surjective systems preserve exactness.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that in general, $\operatorname{Hom}$ commutes with flat base change!

Comment: @FrankScience:  Yes, $Hom$ commutes with flat base change.  Sorry I didn't realize this was the key fact you were looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry, but my answer uses Ext groups, which may not be in the scope of your course.

I don't know of a simple example with finitely generated abelian groups for the following reason: if $0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow E \rightarrow \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z \rightarrow 0$ is an extension represented by $r+n \mathbb Z \in \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, then one can show that $E \cong \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ where $d$ is the highest common factor of $r$ and $n$.  If you assume this sequence doesn't split, then $r$ is not a multiple of $n$ and $d<n$, so the middle term will never be isomorphic to the direct sum of the of the first and third.

However, you can get a simple example using modules in the following way. Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ be an infinite cyclic group and let $\mathbb Z G$ be the associated commutative group ring.  Consider $0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow 0$ a short exact sequence of $\mathbb Z G$-modules where the first map is inclusion into the first component and the second map is projection onto the second.  Let $g$ act on $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ by 
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&1\\ 0&1 
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. Then $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb Z G}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z$ and this extension corresponds to $1$. If you let $g$ act by $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&n\\ 0&1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ it corresponds to $n$. As long as $n>0$ this is a non-split short exact sequence where the direct sum of the outside terms are isomorphic to the middle one.  However, this example is far from elementary, and I apologize for that.

Comment: I should add that there is a 1-1 correspondence between elements of  $Ext^1(C,A)$ and short exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ and this sequence splits iff it corresponds to the $0$ element of the Ext group.

Comment: This looks great, but I don't yet have the tools to understand it. When I do, I will verify it's correct and (probably) accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: In your SES of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules, the middle term is isomorphic to the direct sum of the other two as groups, but not as $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules: $g$ acts trivially on the left and right copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, but not on the middle $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't think the last example is valid. You should study the split-ness of $0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to0$ in *the Abelian category of Abelian groups*, not in the category of $\mathbb ZG$-modules.

Comment: JulianRosen and FrankScience have explained why this example is wrong.  My answer explains why it never had a chance to be right.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer in this question:

[In R-Mod Category, example for $B\cong A \oplus C \nRightarrow 0 \to A \to B \to C \to0$ splits.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038071/in-r-mod-category-example-for-b-cong-a-oplus-c-nrightarrow-0-to-a-to-b-to/3038751#3038751)

It's similar to WillO's.