# If $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is exact and $B\simeq A\oplus C$ as a $R$-module, does this sequence split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Suppose $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence that $B\simeq A\oplus C$ as a $R$-module. Does this short exact sequence split?

I think the answer is **no**, but I must have a counterexample. I could not find any. Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain what you thought about, and generally try to follow this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1804/26369

Comment: I tried to make a short exact sequence that doesnt split but $B\simeq A\oplus C$ !I used $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ because the only homomorphism between them is zero but I couldnt make the hypothesis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't quite a duplicate, the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$ is thoroughly discussed in [A nonsplit short exact sequence of abelian groups with $B \cong A \oplus C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c).