# Example of a non-splitting exact sequence $0 → M → M\oplus N → N → 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Recently, someone stated that every short exact sequence (of, say, modules) of the form
$$0 → M → M \oplus N → N → 0$$
splits. I think this is false in general because the arrow $M → M \oplus N$ might not be the natural inclusion. (The difference pointwise isomorphic/diagramwise isomorphic.)

Maybe one can realize an arrow $M\oplus N → N$ with a kernel isomorphic to $M$, but not being an (internal) direct summand of $M \oplus N$? I tried something along the lines of $ℚ$ and $ℚ/ℤ$, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Can anyone provide me with a counterexample?

Comment: Something is confusing me, by definition that sequence splits, I do not see anything to be proven there. Maybe this can help http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SplitExactSequence.html

Comment: My guess is that you're allowing the maps to not be the usual ones. Is that right?

Comment: @Hoot et al. Yes, of course. I added the explanation. There’s a difference between diagrams being pointwise isomorphic and being isomorphic, well, as diagrams.

Comment: I realized my question already has an (exactly the same) answer already within [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It took me a while, but I came up with a counterexample myself:
$$0 → ℤ \overset α \longrightarrow ℤ \oplus \bigoplus_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ \overset β \longrightarrow \bigoplus_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ → 0,$$
with

- $α$ being multiplication by $2$ (postcomposed by the natural inclusion)
- $β$ being given on the left summand as the projection $ℤ → ℤ/2ℤ$ (postcomposed by the inclusion into the first summand) and on the right summand as a right shift.

More concretely, set $M = ℤ$ and $N = \bigoplus_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ$

\begin{align*}
α&\colon M → M \oplus N,~k ↦ (2k,0)\\
β&\colon M \oplus N → N,~ (k,(κ_1,κ_2,…)) ↦ ([k]_2,κ_1,κ_2,…)
\end{align*}
Now $\ker β = 2ℤ \oplus 0 = \operatorname{img} α$, because for all $x = (k,κ) ∈ M \oplus N$ with $κ = (κ_1,κ_2,…)$
$$ β(x) = 0 ⇔ ([k]_2,κ_1,κ_2,…) = 0 ⇔ k ∈ 2ℤ~\text{and}~κ = 0.$$

The sequence doesn’t split, though, because the element $x = (1,0,0,…)$ in $N$ has order $2$, but there is no element of order $2$ in $β^{-1}(x) = (1,0) + \ker β = (1,0) + (2ℤ\oplus 0)$, so there cannot be any linear map $s \colon N → M \oplus N$ with $(β∘s) (x) = x$ (as $β∘s$ strictly decreases the order of $x$).

Comment: Is there an example with finitely generated modules? If $0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M \oplus N \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow 0$ is exact and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated, then the sequence splits?

Comment: My question in the case $R$ is a $k$- algebra with finite dimension over $k$. If $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated over an arbitrary ring, I don't know.

Comment: @WernerGermánBusch Let $R = \prod_ℕ ℤ$. Then an anologous construction of an exact sequence
$$0 → ℤ →ℤ \oplus \prod_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ → \prod_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ → 0$$
should work. Both $M = ℤ$ and $N =  \prod_ℕ ℤ/2ℤ$ are finitely generated over $R$. I don’t know what happens if $R$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field.

Comment: I was about to say that if $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field, then it's true, using the $Hom(-,A)$ funtor and using dimensions.

Comment: Is there a counterexample where the first injective map is the canonical inclusion map ?

Comment: @Werner Germán Busch: for finitely generated modules over Noetherian rings, there are no counterexamples, see the answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80002/do-all-exact-1-to-a-to-a-times-b-to-b-to-1-split-for-finite-groups