# Proposition 3.2.7 of Bland on short exact sequences, part 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I am reading the book of Bland, *Rings and their Modules* (2011). My question is related to proposition 3.2.7 on page 85.

Given a short exact sequence $S_1: 0\longrightarrow M_1\stackrel{\alpha}\longrightarrow M\stackrel{\beta}\longrightarrow M_2\longrightarrow 0$ of left or right $R$-modules and given $M\cong M_1\oplus M_2$. $R$ may commutative or noncommutative.

I am looking for an example in which $\operatorname{im} \alpha = \ker \beta$ is NOT a direct summand of $M$. (Thus $S_1$ cannot be split.)

This question is related to these two posts:

[Proposition 3.2.7 of Bland on short exact sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884126/proposition-3-2-7-of-bland-on-short-exact-sequences)

[Example of a non-splitting exact sequence $0 → M → M\oplus N → N → 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082283/example-of-a-non-splitting-exact-sequence-0-%e2%86%92-m-%e2%86%92-m-oplus-n-%e2%86%92-n-%e2%86%92-0)

Comment: It seems like the second post you've cited answers your question, no?

Comment: Maybe, can you prove it ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of a non-splitting exact sequence $0 → M → M\oplus N → N → 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082283/example-of-a-non-splitting-exact-sequence-0-%e2%86%92-m-%e2%86%92-m-oplus-n-%e2%86%92-n-%e2%86%92-0)

Comment: Maybe, but can you prove that im f is not a direct summand of M? @Mr Chip, I don't see the relation with my problem, I am talking about modules and not about groups, abelian or not.

Comment: First, abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  Second, the link on the splitting lemma is valid for any abelian category; in particular, it works for any module category.  Third, the splitting lemma will tell you that the image of $\alpha$ is a direct summand of $M$ *if and only if* the sequence is split.  Hence, if you have already shown that a sequence is not split, then you have your example.

Comment: But! In the Splitting lemma of Mr. Chip is this valid: S1 is left split iff Im G is direct summand of M? In prop 3.2.7 of Bland (1), (2) and (3) are not equivalent. In my view, this contradicts the Splitting Lemma.

Comment: Of course, you are right, Pierre-Guy, But I am very curious for a direct proof. I think it will enlighten my understanding. Maybe it makes no sense, but I want to know.

Comment: Im G must be im q, see above.

Comment: It is not a contradiction if it is given that q and r are the natural inclusion and projection, respectively.