# Split Short Exact Sequence of Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that we have a short exact sequence of $K$-algebras, for a field $K$.
$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0,$$ where $A$ is isomorphic to some ideal of $B$ and $B/A \simeq C$ as  $K$-algebras.

If this SES splits does that automatically mean that $B \simeq A \oplus C$ as $K$-algebras? I know that, as vector spaces ($K$-modules) they are certainly split.

I vaguely recall that this 'split' iff 'direct sum' property is not necessarily true, but I'm unable to find a resource that actually shows this, and I'm starting to wonder if I just made it up because rings and algebras are poorly behaved mathematical structures.

Comment: What is a short exact sequence in the category of $K$-algebras?

Comment: Are you working with unital $K$-algebras? If so, then short exact squences aren't very interesting, because for $B/A$ to make sense, $A$ needs to be an ideal in $B$. But if it's also supposed to be a unital $K$-algebra, then $A=B$ and $C=0$

Comment: To address the 'split iff direct sum' property: When an exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ splits, then certainly you have $B \cong A \oplus C$. However the converse is not necessarily true, there are sequences $0 \to A \to A \oplus C \to C \to 0$ that are not split, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082283/example-of-a-non-splitting-exact-sequence-0-%e2%86%92-m-%e2%86%92-m-oplus-n-%e2%86%92-n-%e2%86%92-0/1082313#1082313) to have a counterexample when working with modules.

Comment: @dan_fulea. In the category of $K$-algebras, a short exact sequence consists of two unital algebras $B$ and $C$ and a non-unital algebra $A$ such that: 1) $A \simeq I$ for some ideal of $B$, 2) $B/I \simeq C$, 3) There exist unital homomorphisms $\phi: A \rightarrow B$, and $\psi: B \rightarrow C$, such that $\ker(\psi) = \text{im}(\phi)$.