# Splitting of Lie algebra extensions: why does this linear map exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, exact-sequence

Let $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be finite dimensional Lie algebras and let $(\tilde{\mathfrak{g}},j,\phi)$ be a Lie algebra extension of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $\mathfrak{b}$, so we have a short exact sequence of Lie algebras$$
0\to\mathfrak{b}\xrightarrow{\;\;j\;\;}\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}\xrightarrow{\;\;\phi\;\;}\mathfrak{g}\to0
$$
as in [page 15 of these notes by Erik van den Ban](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Eban00101/lecnotes/repq.pdf#page=15). Then, the author chooses a linear map $\xi:\mathfrak{g}\to\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$ such that $\phi\circ\xi=Id_{\mathfrak{g}}$. If $\xi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, it means that the central extension splits but it is just assumed to be linear. Why does this map exist? I read on here that every short exact sequence of vector spaces splits, is there an intuitive reason why that is true?

Comment: It suffices to define $\xi$ on a basis of $\frak{g}$.

Comment: I have to define it using $\phi$ I suppose?

Comment: If I understand correctly the question is unrelated to Lie algebras...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions of vector spaces split, but not extensions of Lie algebras in general. So "this homomorphism $\xi$" need not exist. Consider an example, i.e., a non-split extension of the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra:

[Non-split extension of Lie algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283038/non-split-extension-of-lie-algebra)

For vector spaces, or more generally for $R$-modules see here:

[Why any short exact sequence of vector spaces may be seen as a direct sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105081/why-any-short-exact-sequence-of-vector-spaces-may-be-seen-as-a-direct-sum)

[A question about split short exact sequence of modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110747/a-question-about-split-short-exact-sequence-of-modules)