# A short exact sequence with $M=M_1 \oplus M_2$ that does not split

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

> A sequence of $R$-modules of the form
>   $$0 \to M_1 \stackrel{f}{\to} M \stackrel{g}{\to} M_2 \to 0$$
>   is called a short exact sequence (ses) if $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective and $\operatorname{Im} f = \operatorname{Ker} g$.
>
> A short exact sequence is said to split if there exist a $R$-homomorphism $h: M_2 \to M$ such that $g\circ h = \operatorname{Id}_{M_2}$.
>
> It is well known that if a short exact sequence split then $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$.

What I am interested in is the converse. I know that the converse is not true. That is, there exist a short exact sequence with $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$ which does not split. I wish to construct such a counter example.

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M_1=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $M'=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose we have a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $N$ such that $M_1\oplus N \cong N$ and $M' \oplus N \cong N$. Define $M= M'\oplus N$, and $M_2=M_1\oplus N$. Then
$$M_1\oplus M_2 \cong M_1 \oplus N \cong N \cong M' \oplus N = M$$
Then consider the sequence
$$0 \to M_1 \stackrel{f}{\to} M \stackrel{g}{\to} M_2 \to 0$$
where $f:M_1\to M=M''\oplus N$ is defined as $f(\bar{1})=(\bar{2},0)$ and $g: M \to M_2$ as $g(\bar{x},n)=(\bar{x},n)$. Then clearly $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective and $\operatorname{Im} f = \operatorname{Ker} g$.

Suppose the ses splits. Then $h :M_2 \to M$ is such that $g\circ h =\operatorname{Id}_{M_2}$. But then
$$h(\bar{1},0) \in  g^{-1}(\bar{1},0)=\{\bar{1},0),(\bar{3},0)\}$$
But $2(\bar{1},0)=(\bar{2},0)$ and $2(\bar{3},0)=(\bar{2},0)$ in $M$. Thus
$$h(\bar{0},0)=2h(\bar{1},0)=(\bar{2},0)$$
which contradicts the fact that $h$ is a homomorphism. Thus the ses does not splits.

The only thing that remains to show the existence of such an $N$. However, I am no able to show that such an $N$ does exists. Any help/ suggestions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c

Comment: Please always search the site. We have had maaaaaaaany questions already, and there is always a good chance that one's question has already been asked.

Comment: Thanks @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez . I did search with keywords "short exact sequence" and "split". But it is always difficult to search latex things like $M=M_1\oplus M_2$.

Comment: Use Google to search. I searched for exactly the same terms, and with typos and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be a direct sum of infinitely many copies of $M_1$ and infinitely many copies of $M'$.  Since adding one element to an infinite set doesn't change its cardinality, $M_1\oplus N\cong N$ and $M'\oplus N\cong N$.