# Splitting of an exact sequence of abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Let $0\to A\xrightarrow{f} A\oplus B\xrightarrow{g}B\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of (finite) abelian groups, then must it be split exact? If not, can you show me some examples? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: If I emphisize that  A and B are finite abelian groups, is it split?

Comment: Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891527/60713