# non-split short exact sequence $A\rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ with $B \cong A\oplus B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, exact-sequence

From this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c), it says that any counter example can not be finitely generated Abelian groups. But I can not find the mistake in the following counter example, I must missed something obvious,
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{ z\times2 \oplus z\text{ mod }2} \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \xrightarrow{ \text{ mod }2\circ\pi_\mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0.$$

The first map is injective, second map is surjective, and the image of first map is the kernel of the second map.

And it fails to be exact with the same reason for $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{z\times 2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow {(\text{mod }2)}\mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0$, there is no non-zero homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/2$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your first map is $a\mapsto(2a,\overline a)$. I cannot
read what your second map is. But the image $I$ of the first map
has index $4$ in $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2$, so it cannot be the
kernel of your second map. Observe that $(0,\overline 0)$, $(0,\overline 1)$, $(1,\overline 0)$ and $(1,\overline 1)$ are in distinct cosets of
$I$.

Comment: The second map is projection onto the first component (which is $\mathbb{Z}$) then compose mod 2.

Comment: So it is $(a,\overline b)\mapsto\overline a$. Then $(0,\overline 1)$ is in its kernel but not in the image of the first map. @Xiao

Comment: I see,  thank you very much!