# Does an embedding necessarily make a short exact sequence split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Suppose we have a short exact sequence.

$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$.

Suppose also that we know there is some embedding $e : C \hookrightarrow B$.

Can we conclude that the sequence splits? It seems that we should be able to, but it is not required that $e$ be a section of the surjection $B \to C$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason for this to hold. For example, there is a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$
but it doesn't split since $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. And even a sequence with $B\cong A\oplus C$ need not split in general, as can be seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c).