# When does a short exact sequence of groups imply it is isomorphic to direct product group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ is a short exact sequence of groups.

Then, what is a (necessary and )sufficient condition for $G\cong N\times Q$.

In other words, let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, then what is a (necessary and )sufficient condition for $G\cong G/N\times N$.

Comment: Try to use the splitting lemma! It's very useful here, Regards!

Comment: @AlexisOsorio isn't that for Abelian groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For abelian groups (or even in any abelian category) you can use the splitting lemma:

**Proposition 1.** Let $0 \longrightarrow A' \stackrel{f}\longrightarrow A \stackrel{g}\longrightarrow A'' \longrightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of abelian groups. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) There exists a homomorphism $h \colon A \rightarrow A'$ such that $h \circ f = \text{id}_{A'}.$

(ii) There exists a homomorphism $j \colon A'' \rightarrow A$ such that $g \circ j = \text{id}_{A''}.$

(iii) We have an isomorphism $h \colon A \rightarrow A' \oplus A''$, such that $h \circ f$ is the natural inclusion of $A'$ into the direct sum $A' \oplus A''$ and $g \circ h^{-1}$ is the natural projection from $A' \oplus A''$ onto $A''$.

For non-abelian groups the splitting lemma does not hold in general. Consider for example the short exact sequence $1 \longrightarrow A_n \stackrel{\iota}\longrightarrow S_n \stackrel{\text{sgn}}\longrightarrow C_2 \longrightarrow 1$. We can send the generator of $C_2$ to any $2$-cycle to get (ii), but (i) and (iii) do not hold.

Let me now rephrase the splitting lemma for general groups:

**Proposition 2.** Let $1 \longrightarrow G' \stackrel{f}\longrightarrow G \stackrel{g}\longrightarrow G'' \longrightarrow 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) There exists a homomorphism $h \colon G \rightarrow G'$ such that $h \circ f = \text{id}_{G'}.$

(ii) There exists an isomorphism $\alpha \colon G \rightarrow G' \times G''$ such that $\alpha \circ f = i_1$ and $p_2 \circ \alpha = g$. Here $i_1 \colon G' \rightarrow G' \times G''$ is the inclusion into the first factor and $p_2 \colon G' \times G'' \rightarrow G''$ is the projection onto the second factor.

You can also get another version:

**Proposition 3.** Let $1 \longrightarrow G' \stackrel{f}\longrightarrow G \stackrel{g}\longrightarrow G'' \longrightarrow 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) There exists a homomorphism $j \colon G'' \rightarrow G$ such that $g \circ j = \text{id}_{G''}.$

(ii) There exists a homomorphism $\varphi \colon G'' \rightarrow \text{Aut}(G')$, such that $\beta \colon G' \rtimes G'' \rightarrow G$, $(a,b) \mapsto f(a)j(b)$ is an isomorhpism.

Comment: In all these statements the isomorphisms should be related to the maps in the original sequence!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me add that.

Comment: Let me add a reference as to why this is important: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c

Comment: @Con Is the Proposition 2 true for any isomorphism $\alpha$ of groups from $G$ to $G' \times G''$? Specifically, I wanted to know more about how do you say the second part implies the first, when the $h$ itself was defined in the first part. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @ReaderManifold Oh yes, this is indeed written quite poorly. Let me quickly change it.

Comment: Before I just constructed $\alpha$ in terms of $h$, which shows how (i) implies (ii).