# exact sequence $A\to B\to C$ with $B\cong A\oplus C$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C$ be an exact sequence of finitely generated abelian groups with $B\cong A\oplus C$.

*Question:* Is the sequence **short exact**?

If $B$ is finite, the answer is clear positive.

Is there a counterexample to show that the finiteness assumption on $B$ is vital? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add one more assumption: $A,C$ are nontrivial.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c?rq=1) might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Specialize the claim to $A=0$ and $B=C$. This means that all injective homomorphisms are surjective, which needs not be true (see multiplication by a constant on $\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I want to add some ''nice'' conditions to make the original sequence short exact, so I think I forgot the assumption that $A,C$ are nontrivial.